# OnCollisionEnter not working Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to build a game where u need to dodge falling objects. I've made a hazard but it seems as if the hazard 'clone' is behaving diffrently.

I've made a collision script when the hazard hits the platform it needs to disappear. This works for the hazard object, but not the hazard clone objects that fall.

- As u can see in the first screenshot, the red circled block behaves
  like it use to. But the blue circled once (clones) fall right through
  objects.
- As u can see in the second screenshot, the red circled one is gone,
  because it hit the platform. But still the blue once fall right
  through.

Thanks in advance!

[image]
[image]

**Below u will find the Collision script, below that is the Hazard Spawn script:**

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class HazardCollisionFunctions : MonoBehaviour {

 #region Variables
 //Public

 //Private
 #endregion

 #region UnityFunctions
 void Start()
 {

 }
 void Update()
 {

 }
 #endregion

 private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
 {
     if(collision.gameObject.tag == "platform")
     {
         this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
     }

     if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
     {

     }
 }
 }
```

---

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnHazards : MonoBehaviour {

#region Variables
//Public

//Private
[SerializeField]
public float minX = 0.0f;
[SerializeField]
public float maxX = 0.0f;
[SerializeField]
private GameObject[] hazards;        //potential array of hazards
[SerializeField]
private float timeBetweenSpawns = 0.0f;
private bool canSpawn = false;
private int amountOfHazardsToSpawn = 0;
private int hazardToSpawn = 0;
#endregion

#region UnityFunctions
public void Start()
{
    canSpawn = true;    //Temp start
}
public void Update()
{
    if(canSpawn == true)
    {
        StartCoroutine("GenerateHazard");
    }
}
#endregion

private IEnumerator GenerateHazard()
{
    canSpawn = false;
    timeBetweenSpawns = Random.Range(0.5f, 2.0f);       //Testing values
    amountOfHazardsToSpawn = Random.Range(1, 5);        //Testing values
    for(int i = 0; i < amountOfHazardsToSpawn; i ++)
    {
        Vector3 spawnPos = new Vector3(Random.Range(minX, maxX), 8.0f, 0.0f);   //Gen spawnpoint for the hazard
        Instantiate(hazards[hazardToSpawn], spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);     //Spawn the hazard
    }
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeBetweenSpawns);
    canSpawn = true;
}
}
```

Comment: Which object has which tag? Do you falling objects want to pass through player but collide with the platform?

Comment: @UmairM The tags are as followed: Blue box = "Player'', Red Box = "hazard", white platform = "platform''. 

The fallen objects need to collide with the platform ''dissappear when it hits the platform'' And if they collide with the player it's game over.

Comment: Make sure all the objects have isTrigger property unchecked on the collider component

Comment: Oke i've looked through the objects, none of them have isTrigger property checked, except for the ''Clone hazard'' that spawn in.

Comment: You have assigned those prefabs in the array from the inspector. Check the prefabs because they have isTrigger=true

Comment: you're right! It now works as it should. Many many thanks for the help! (:

Comment: A lot of new users face this problem so I have added a detailed answer, please mark it correct and upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

### OnCollisionEnter

[**`OnCollisionEnter`**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html) takes [**`Collision`**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision.html) object as a parameter and it requires the **`isTrigger`** property of the attached `Collider` component to be **FALSE**.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    foreach (ContactPoint contact in collision.contacts)
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(contact.point, contact.normal, Color.white);
    }
}
```

---

### OnTriggerEnter

[**`OnTriggerEnter`**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) takes [**`Collider`**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html) object as a parameter and it requires the **`isTrigger`** property of the attached `Collider` component to be **TRUE**.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("CheckPoint"))
    {
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
}
```

---

> 1. If you are instantiating the object from `prefab`, make sure that
>      `prefab` have required components (`rigidbody`/`collider`) and
>      properties to achieve the desired behaviour.
> 2. To detect Collision/Trigger, at least one of the object must have a
>      physics component ([`Rigidbody`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html))
> 3. Rigidbody **MUST** be attached to the **moving** object.

---

Hope this helps :)