# How do I know if box collider 2d is touching another box collider?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a game 2D, I'm using `Unity 3D 5.6.1f1` with `C#` . 
I have a `Collider Box 1` and   `Collider Box 2`.

How do I know if `Collider Box 1` touch `Collider Box 2` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47753598/4366237

Comment: Why so few newbies follow the [Unity tutorials](https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/s/physics)? [I downvoted because this question does not show research effort](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/)

Comment: Since this is 2D collider, The `IsTouchingXXX` functions makes more sense.  Please research your next question before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Umair M has a good link above, but I wanted to add that what your searching for is "collision detection" which if I understand correctly is done through OnCollisionEnter in unity and is covered in detail here here:

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/detecting-collisions-oncollisionenter

But for you specific question Umair is correct to point you to:

[OnCollisionEnter not working Unity3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752522/oncollisionenter-not-working-unity3d/47753598#47753598)