# Can someone assist with collision of Unity 3d colliders

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d

I am trying to create a stealth game and I created and enemy and attached box collider component to the eyes of the enemy with IsTrigger is checked so that cube serves as vision and whenever a player enters that trigger, the enemy starts going after the player. The problem is as soon as a player enters and exit the trigger, the player glitches by swiftly sitting and standing, perhaps due to collisions of colliders of my player and enemy vision cube. I don't know, maybe it happens because of Unity itself and need to update the program or something like that.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemyWalk : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject Enemy;
    public float timer;
    public bool yes;
    public float newtimer;


    void Start () {
        newtimer=timer;

    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
        if (other.tag == "Player") {
            Enemy.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>().enabled = true;
                Enemy.GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger ("MoveForEnemy");


        }
    }
    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other){
        if(other.tag == "Player") {
        yes=true;
        }



    }
    void Update () {
        if(yes==true){
            timer -= Time.deltaTime;  
        }
        if(timer < 0){
                Enemy.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>().enabled = false;
            yes=false;
            timer=newtimer;
                Enemy.GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger ("IdleForEnemy");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: are you using onTriggerEnter and onTriggerExit or onCollisionEnter/Exit.  for the box that is a trigger use the onTrigger versions? You may have a overlap of collision code as you have stated. Also for a 'look' trigger. Look at raycasthit instead. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-collider.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer mushcraft, I use OnTriggerEnter and OnTriggerExit. I used all types of colliders but ,you know, once the player crosses the border of a collider, the player just sit and stand in a quick manner and the same happens when exiting trigger

Comment: Add your code to question and for general information have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47753598/4366237

Comment: I have added the code below

Comment: Since you have stated the enemy does moves to the player what about scripts attached to the player? The sitting/standing glitch. Do you have a sit animation? Could you have a collision or bool trigger attach being set that controls your player animation? for example the onExit yes = true. As it's public are you assigning in the properties panel with a a bool/property from a global game object and a your animationController is using the same bool?